# What's the best caulk type for exterior stucco to wood window trim?

Tags: windows, paint, trim, stucco, caulk

I have cracked caulk that is sealing window trim to a stucco wall. What type of caulk should I use to replace the old, deteriorated caulk?

Ideally, the caulk would be paintable.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion the best caulk for almost any siding job is urethane. It's crazy sticky, paints well (and comes in a zillion colors to match pre-finished siding by special order), and remains flexible.

Caveat: As I said, it's crazy sticky. It will remain on your skin for days and your clothing forever. You'll want to use a small, well-shaped nozzle and practice beforehand. Ideally, there's no additional tooling to be done. The nozzle does the tooling.

Comment: Is this still your recommendation?  If you aren't tooling it with your finger then the end visual is going to be the bead produced by the caulking gun as you pull it away from the surface?  What about areas that have high visibility, you wouldn't rather use a silicon caulking tool to give it an appearance more akin to interior finger applied caulking?

Comment: I don't finger out caulk for interiors, either. That almost always spreads the caulk way too far. I want a small, flat bead with no feathered edge.

Comment: My usual technique is to cut about  30° angle on the nozzle, as small as possible, and slice the sharp tip off 90° from that, creating a flat that trowels the caulk surface.